# Ext splitter - programmatically changing its position

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I have a panel with 3 items in it. A panel then a horizontal splitter then a panel. This layout works fine and the user can easily drag the splitter up and down to resize the adjoining panels.

But how do I set the position of the splitter programmatically? Ideally I'd like to animate the splitter to its new position.

The splitter has a method `setPosition`, which also takes an animate argument. But this method simply moves the splitter without changing the heights of either panel. So the splitter is now floating over the top of one of the panels. In the `afteranimate` listener I've tried all manner of doLayout, updateLayout, panel.setHeight, etc... but nothing seems to affect the panel sizes. According to the console the code is run, it just doesn't appear to do anything.

So what is the method for changing the position of a horizontal position between two panels?

This is using Ext 4.1.1a.

```
splitter.setPosition(0,30,{
    listeners:{
        beforeanimate: function(){
            console.log('animate');
        },
        afteranimate: function(){
            console.log('finished');
            bottomPanel.setHeight(500);  //Does nothing
            splitter.updateLayout(); //Does nothing
            rightColumn.doLayout();  // Puts splitter bar back to the original position
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: perhaps if you set the new heights of the two panels, and then doLayout for the split panel. Or just doLayout for the split panel without setting the heights manually.

Comment: Setting the heights of both panels then calling dolayout doesn't appear to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved a very similar problem with ExtJS 4.1.3.  I have two panels separated by a vertical splitter and I wanted the splitter position to persist across page refreshes.

After trying for some time trying to hook into the splitter itself, I abandoned the idea. The way I have been able to set the splitter position programmatically starts by listening to the resize event of one of the panels.

I store the width of the sidebar with the ExtJS state manager. If the new width parameter is undefined, then this is a page reload situation and I grab the last saved sidebar panel width from the state manager.  I set the width of the sidebar to the saved value, then set the splitter position to 20 pixels more than the width (to account I assume for the scrollbar.)

Inside the sidebar panel:

```
resize: function (sidebar, newWidth, newHeight, oldWidth, oldHeight) {
    var sidebarWidth = newWidth;
    if (oldWidth === undefined) {
        // page reload. restore width from state manager
        savedWidth = Ext.state.Manager.get('sidebar_width');
        sidebarWidth = savedWidth === undefined ? sidebarWidth : savedWidth;
    }
    sidebar.splitter.setPosition(sidebarWidth + 20);
    sidebar.setWidth(sidebarWidth);
    Ext.state.Manager.set('sidebar_width', sidebarWidth);
}
```

I had avoided setting a listener inside a panel because I didn't know how to get a handle to the splitter object.  The breakthrough came when I discovered that the context parameter sent into the resize event (named sidebar in the example code provided) holds a reference to the splitter object.

This solution worked for me and hopefully it will be helpful to others with this question.